# Mathjax preview in popup is not working

Tags: php, jquery, mathjax

I have list of questions and every question have a hyperlink. When I click on a particular question a popup window opens and show question detail. I am saving encoded math equation in db and show there decoded form in popup preview. First time it work fine but after that it is unable to load decoded equation. I am using mathjax for this purpose. My Popup page code is -

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
      showProcessingMessages: false,
      tex2jax: { inlineMath: [['$','$'],['\\(','\\)']] }
    });

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_HTMLorMML"></script>
div id="QUESTION_TEXT_PREVIEW" class="math-jx-preview" style="border: none;"><?php echo $equation; ?></div>
```

My input is - `\vec{F} = \frac{d \vec{p}}{dt} = m \frac{d \vec{v}}{dt} = m vec{a}`
and required output is- 
F→=dp→dt=mdv→dt=ma→F→=dp→dt=mdv→dt=ma→

Comment: There is not enough information here. You should add a self-contained example that exhibits the problem.